# Laravel Chart JS change data with dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, chart.js

I'm trying to show data from a chart that gets a specific barangay(village or district) from a dropdown box. So, for example, I have a chart showing the male and female count of one barangay from the last ten years, and I only need to select a specific one from the said dropdown box, and the chart changes shown data. I'm trying to do this via ajax with Chart.js.

**Controller**

```
public function demoHistory()
{
    $gendersbrgy = DB::table('demographics')
        ->selectRaw('sum(case when Q4=\'Male\' then 1 else 0 end) as one,
     sum(case when Q4=\'Female\' then 1 else 0 end) as two,
     year(created_at) as year')
        ->where('currentbrgy', $brgy)
        ->groupBy('brgy', 'year')
        ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
        ->limit(11)
        ->get();

    return response()->json(compact('gendersbrgy');
}
```

The `$brgy` variable in the where clause is where I would put the variable ideally. I'm pretty new to this.

**JavaScript**

```
const brgy = document.getElementById('brgyselector');
brgy.addEventListener('change', changeBrgy);

function changeBrgy() {
    //DO STUFF HERE
}
```

[Chart of Genders with Barangay Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8X0h.png)

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: There is an update function available in the chart.js instance. You can update the data with new records.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `update()` to update chart data on ajax success.
Maybe you can do this:
(There's example chart code that's used in ajax, too)

```
var ctx_live = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx_live, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor:'#00c0ef',
      label: 'liveCount',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js - Dynamically Update Chart Via Ajax Requests",
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

// logic to get new data
var getData = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("brgyselector");
    var strUser = e.value;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'url_to_controller_action',
        success: function(data) {
          // process your data to pull out what you plan to use to update the chart
          // e.g. new label and a new data point
          
          // you can use loop through response data
          // add new label and data point to chart's underlying data structures
          myChart.data.labels.push("Label");
          myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push('set point');
          
          // re-render the chart
          myChart.update();
        }
      });
};

const brgy = document.getElementById('brgyselector');
brgy.addEventListener('change', getData);
```

I have no idea how your ajax response data looks like. So you can modify/set as required while updating chartdata in ajax success.